# Convert Grobid curl command to requests in Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, grobid

I'm trying to convert `curl` script to parse pdf file from [`grobid`](http://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Grobid-service/) server to `requests` in Python.

Basically, if I run the `grobid` server as follows,

```
./gradlew run
```

I can use the following `curl` to get the output of parsed XML of an academic paper `example.pdf` as below

```
curl -v --form input=@example.pdf localhost:8070/api/processHeaderDocument
```

However, I don't know the way to convert this script into Python. Here is my attempt to use `requests`:

```
GROBID_URL = 'http://localhost:8070'
url = '%s/processHeaderDocument' % GROBID_URL
pdf = 'example.pdf'
xml = requests.post(url, files=[pdf]).text
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer. Basically, I missed `api` in the `GROBID_URL` and also the input `files` should be a dictionary instead of a list.

```
GROBID_URL = 'http://localhost:8070'
url = '%s/api/processHeaderDocument' % GROBID_URL
pdf = 'example.pdf'
xml = requests.post(url, files={'input': open(pdf, 'rb')}).text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example bash script from http://ceur-ws.bitplan.com/index.php/Grobid.  Please note that there is also a ready to use python client available. See https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid_client_python

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2020-08-04
# call grobid service with paper from ceur-ws
v=2644
p=44
vol=Vol-$v
pdf=paper$p.pdf
if [ ! -f $pdf ]
then
  wget http://ceur-ws.org/$vol/$pdf
else
  echo "paper $p from volume $v already downloaded" 
fi
curl -v --form input=@./$pdf http://grobid.bitplan.com/api/processFulltextDocument > $p.tei
```